# R Rstudio problems installing packages mapdeck and googlePolylines

Tags: r, rstudio, mapdeck

When I try to install the package mapdeck in Rstudio, it appears a message in the console saying that I need to install the package googlePolylines, but I can't install this one. The error that appears in the console is the following:

> package ‘googlePolylines’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> libs
>
> g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
>
> g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I"/home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c encode.cpp -o encode.o
>
> encode.cpp: In function ‘void encode_vector(std::ostringstream&, std::ostringstream&, Rcpp::List, Rcpp::CharacterVector&, int)’:
>   encode.cpp:175: error: conversion from ‘Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>’ to ‘double’ is ambiguous
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:73: note: candidates are: Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator int() const [with int RTYPE = 19, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:72: note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator bool() const [with int RTYPE = 19, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:67: note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator U() const [with U = double, int RTYPE = 19, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   encode.cpp:176: error: conversion from ‘Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>’ to ‘double’ is ambiguous
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:73: note: candidates are: Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator int() const [with int RTYPE = 19, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:72: note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator bool() const [with int RTYPE = 19, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:67: note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator U() const [with U = double, int RTYPE = 19, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   make: *** [encode.o] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘googlePolylines’
>
> removing ‘/home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/googlePolylines’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘googlePolylines’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/tmp/RtmpwwAJSv/downloaded_packages’

I haven't found almost any information about these two packages, so I would appreciate if anyone could help me, thank you.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: No, I have already solved @SymbolixAU

Comment: Would you mind adding your solution as an answer? It might be helpful for me and others.

Comment: The problem was about some packages that weren't installed yet. The first step is, from the terminal, you have to install the following packages:
`sudo dnf install geos geos-devel;
sudo dnf install gdal gdal-devel;
sudo dnf install proj-devel; 
sudo dnf install proj-nad;
sudo dnf install proj-epsg`.
Then, from CRAN, you have to install both packages `sp` and `rgdal`.
`rgdal` version has to be, at least, 1.3-6.
By doing this I could install `googlePolylines`, and finally `mapdeck `.

Comment: That seems like it's just an issue with `sp`. Neither mapdeck nor googlePolylines require `sp` though, so I'm surprised you got that error with trying to install only those two libraries.